# What are some resources on qubits based on quantum dots?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization, quantum-dots

I would like to learn a bit on the physics and details of manufacture of a qubits based on quantum dots. Can anyone recommend some papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a bibliography in the book *Quantum Computing: An Applied Approach* (ISBN: 9783030239213) or try directly google scholar.

Comment: Do you have a more specific selection of articles in the bibliography in mind? Or does the book you mentioned cover material relevant to the question?